# How to read only the last 3 digits?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I want to get only the last 3 things from `stdin`.

Using

```
scanf("%3d")
```

I can get the first 3, but I want the last 3, and ignore everything before it.

Sample input

```
bkjashfsjak32326321536999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

How can I do that?

If possible I would like to ignore the contents on `stdin` and get only 3 chars on the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're reading an integer. If so (since you're ignoring everything else), you can read the entire thing and take the remainder when divided by 1000.

```
    scanf ("%d", &read_int);
    last_3 = read_int % 1000;
```

**Update:**
Since its not an integer (assuming `some_large_buf` can take your largest string):

```
    scanf ("%s", some_large_buf);
    last_3 = atoi (some_large_buf + strlen(some_large_buf) - 3);
```

**Update 2:**
This version doesn't use a buffer, it maintains a rolling value of the least significant 3 digits.

```
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    char c;
    while (1) {
        scanf ("%c", &c);

        if (c == 0 || c == '\n') break;

        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            sum *= 10; 
            sum += c - '0';
            sum %= 1000;
        }   
        else {
            sum = 0;
        }   
    }   
    printf ("%d", sum);
```

Comment: Doesnt work for `9*9H#2hd2poh2pthpo2hr2hpo9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`

Comment: That works, but is there a way to ignore when reading? So it could fit in a `buffer[4]`?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use `fgets( ... stdin)` to read it into a buffer.  Then you could extract the desired information from the end of the buffer (e.g., use `sscanf` and pass the pointer to the desired start location).  The general idea would be the following.  Note that `fgets` can return a newline character in the returned buffer, so if it is known it will be there it would need to be accounted for.

```
char buf[1024];
char *pos;
size_t len;
int val = 0;

fgets( buf, sizeof( buf ), stdin );
len = strlen( buf );

if ( len < 3 )
  printf( "Not long enough\n" );
else
  sscanf( buf + len - 3, "%d", &val );
```